# preg_replace regex change

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm looking to change some regex I'm using to cater for HTML comment tags instead of CSS.

I've built a preg replace function that can edit between comments in a stylesheet like so:

```
$find = array();
    $find[0] = "/(\/\*bgColor\*\/).*?(\/\*\/bgColor\*\/)/i";
    $find[1] = "/(\/\*titleColor\*\/).*?(\/\*\/titleColor\*\/)/i";
$replace = array();
    $replace[0] = "\\1 background-color: $bgColor; \\2";
    $replace[1] = "\\1 color: $titleColor; \\2";
$result = preg_replace($find, $replace, $file);
```

The way this works is demonstrated below:

```
/*titleColor*/ color: #000; /*/titleColor*/
```

Any content between the two CSS tags will be replaced.

I'm looking to replicate this idea but with html like so:

```
<!--titleColor--> content_to_replace  <!--/titleColor-->
```

What do I need to change in the preg_replace in order for this to work correctly with html comment tags?

Comment: An example of some before/after HTML comment would make it easier for us to understand, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$find = array();
    $find[0] = '/(<!--titleColor-->)(.*?)(<!--\/titleColor-->)/i';
$replace = array();
    $replace[0] = '$1' . 'replacement' . '$3';
// I prefer enclosing the current inner value with patantheses
// in case you might wanna change or use it inside the $replace value.
```